# How can I generate a progressive sequential unique id in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I generate a progressive sequential unique id in PHP?

For example, the order should be this:

aaaaaa < aaaaab < aaaaac etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid) is increasing (an ID generated later will always be greater than one generated earlier) but will not be sequential (there will be gaps).

Otherwise, find a way to save the last generated ID, and increment it when you generate a new one.

Comment: Can also build it into system that You are writing. simply in cfg files create a strat value, that will eventualy be a current value. Everytime You generate a new id, then increment that value.

Comment: This answers fits well in my solution but I had to modify my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This is by default in PHP `Incrementing/Decrementing Operators` can work directly with Strings please see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

```
$start = "aaaaaa" ;
$start++;
$start++;
var_dump($start);
```

Output

```
  string 'aaaaac' (length=6)
```

Comment: +1 Works perfectly! I had no idea you could do that. And it keeps going past 6 chars. Can't get much more concise than that :)

Comment: PHP Sometimes rocks ... this would take a lot of coding is most other languages ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = 'aaaax';
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
    $id++;
    echo "$id\n";
}
```

demo
http://codepad.org/ogGrOfyQ

Answer (score 0):

If you use any of the other solutions here, you'll still have to fetch or save the last id and then increment it. Instead, you could simply use the auto-incremented id and convert it into a textual representation.

I'm using Laravel examples here, but you can apply the theory to any framework.

```
// Save your model.
$flight = new Flight;
$flight->name = $request->name;
$flight->save();

// $flight->id now contains the last inserted id.
echo base_convert($flight->id, 10, 36);

// Output: 1E86
```

Base 10 is numbers from 0-9. Base 36 adds the 26 letters of the alphabet to that.

Note that there is no need to actually save the output back to the database, which would take another query and defeat the purpose of this optimisation. Instead, you can add a mutator that converts the id in real time:

```
class Flight extends Model {
    ...
    public function getUniqueIdAttribute()
    {
        return base_convert($this->id, 10, 36);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply save your model and call `$flight->uniqueId` and get your base 36 converted id.

Tip: Add a salt value to the id to prevent leaking actual database ids.